# I am not able to toast messages in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-toast

I have created an `add` button. No data is entered in the `EditText` field and when the user press the button I am not able to `Toast` the message.

```
If(text1.getText( ).toString( ).matches(" ") || text2.getText( ).toString( ).matches(" "))
{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"input values",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT.show( );
}
```

Comment: I have tried all these, but it shows "calculator keeps stopping".

Answer (score 1):

You are matching wrong string. Instead of `.match(" ")` use `.match("")` or it is better to use `text1.getText().toString().isEmpty()`. In fact your if block never reached.

Comment: I have tried all these, but it shows "calculator keeps stopping".

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
EditText usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
sUsername = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
if (sUsername.matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code and IF condition like this:

```
If (String.valueOf(text1.getText()).equals("") || String.valueOf(text2.getText()).equals(""))
{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"input values",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

That's all,

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `trim()` this function will remove spaces.

```
  If(text1.getText( ).toString( ).trim().equals("") || text2.getText( ).toString.trim().equals(""))
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You did not enter a username and password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT.show( );
    }
```

I hope this will helpful.